# Clean vector with loop

Tags: matlab, loops

I wrote a code that finds the first zero, compares the values before and after the zero and deletes the zero and the smaller number. But I don't understand why i get the error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in bereinigen (line 9)
>       C1=L(A1+1);

```
L=[-300   100     0   200  -100   100 0 -300 ];

A3=find(L==0);
U=length(A3);
for x=1:U
    A1=A3(x);
    C1=L(A1+1);
    C2=L(A1-1);
    B1=sign(C1);
    B2=sign(C2);
    if B1==B2
        D1=min(C1,C2);
            if D1==C1
                L(A1+1)=[];
                E1=find(L==0);
                E1=E1(1);
                L(E1)=[];
            elseif D1==C2
                L(A1-1)=[];
                E1=find(L==0);
                E1=E1(1);
                L(E1)=[];
            end
    else
        return
    end
end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You are removing elements from `L` so the indexes specified by `A3` can potentially refer to positions beyond `L` if you remove enough values since you only compute `A3` from the *entire* vector

Comment: ah yes, you are right! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use logical indexing to mark indeces for deletion and then remove them after the loop

```
L=[-300 100 0 200 -100 100 0 -300 ];
Inds = true(size(L));
A3=find(L==0);
U=length(A3);
for x=1:U
    A1=A3(x);
    C1=L(A1+1);
    C2=L(A1-1);
    B1=sign(C1);
    B2=sign(C2);
    if B1==B2
        D1=min(C1,C2);
        if D1==C1
            Inds(A1+1)=false;
            Inds(A1)=false;
        elseif D1==C2
            Inds(A1-1)=false;
            Inds(A1)=false;
        end
    else
        break
    end
end
L = L(Inds);
```

Beware that `L(A1+1)` could also yield an out of bounds error. You should try to handle that posibility.